# stopPreview/takePhoto stops freezing image after setPictureSize to camera parameters

Tags: android, android-camera

So I am making an application where you can take some pictures.

I had everything working as it should besides of the PictureSize.
After you take a picture, the preview is supposed to freeze with the last image taken, just like TakePhoto usually do for you. This works as it should until i do `parameters.setPictureSize` in this method:

```
public void setupCameraParameters() {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        Camera.Size preSize = determineBestPreviewSize(parameters);
        Camera.Size picSize = determineBestPictureSize(parameters);

        parameters.setPreviewSize(preSize.width, preSize.height);
        parameters.setPictureSize(picSize.width, picSize.height);
        parameters.setRotation(90);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    }
```

This gives my pictures the correct sizes, however what happends now is that my preview doesn't freeze after TakePhoto is called, it just keeps feeding from my camera.

I have even tried doing `mCamera.stopPreviewing()` without any freezing images. If i release the camera, the image gets black as it should do so I really am working on the right camera-instance as well.

Is there any documentation I have missed? Have someone else entered this problem before.

EDIT:
So I got back my xperia z3 compact from repair and checked this issue again. On z3 this never is an issue, the code will take a picture and then freeze the preview like I want it to. My other phone was a HTC one (m7).

Comment: What do you mean by `the image gets black as it should do`?

Comment: I mean that the preview gets black/disabled/released (Not getting anymore stream) just as it should do when you release the camera.

Comment: I have the same issue with a HTC One M7. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: I did not solve it. It was just that particular device that i tested on that didn't work and that wasn't worth fixing at the time. Good luck